# Deploy Squirrel applications with Octopus

Tags: octopus-deploy, squirrel.windows

I'm interested if someone has managed to deploy a Squirrel installer (https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows) with the Octopus workflow. I've had a ClickOnce deployment running just fine with it, but with Squirrel I need access to the nupkg, the ability to run some XML transform, and finally run a command line to push it to a UNC location. So it actually never reaches a remote machine to be installed. 
I realise Octopus has a different primary focus for delivery, but I wanted to know if someone has manged to figure out a way to do this.

Thanks for any input on this, 
C.

Comment: I've been able to deploy click once applications using OD before. Again, it needs access to the NuGet package to perform xml transformations, and there's an additional step to resign the manifest and repackage the click once app, but it can all be done as library steps in OD. Would a solution based on this help as I don't know Squirrel, but imagine the process would be fairly similar.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://chaseflorell.github.io/devops/2015/08/07/deploying-squirrel.windows-apps-with-octopus-deploy/. It looks like a good walkthrough.